# IQueryable.Select always returns null

Tags: c#, linq, tfs

I tried to implement a small LINQ-To-TFS Provider, found here: http://linqtfs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest, which seems to work.
The problem: We're using the Facade-Pattern, so the Client (the GUI in this Case) works with a SimpleSalesItem-Model, but ofc the TFS-DataLayer should work with the WorkItem-Model.

So I hoped I could do something like this, in fact someone else told me to do so:

```
    internal static IEnumerable<SimpleSalesItem> Get(Expression<Func<SimpleSalesItem, bool>> filter)
    {
        var t = DataLayer.TFS.TFS.Query().Select(f => new SimpleSalesItem()
        {
            //Setting the properties of SimpleSalesItem
        }).Where(filter);
```

Sadly, Even if I do

```
        var t2 = DataLayer.TFS.TFS.Query().Where(f => f.Id >= 123);
        var t3 = t2.Select(f => f.Id);
```

t3 is always null.
Is that not possible to do this way? How would you create a easy solution to get two Expressions along together?

Thanks in advance

Matthias

Comment: Do you genuinely mean `null`? Or do you mean it has no data? (i.e. `t3.Any()` is `false`)

Comment: NULL, funny enought. Is the Implementation of the LINQ to TFS Provider the cause here? Would there have to be a special Procedure overridden?

Comment: Initially, I did not believe that `Queryable.Select` would ever return `null` but as it just delegates the task to the query provider it can in fact return `null`. Surely, this is a bug in the TFS query provider where [`IQueryProvider.CreateQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549139(v=vs.100).aspx) returns `null`.

Comment: Yeah, this basically says "buggy LINQ provider"